# How to implement the seekto functionality in ionic 4?

Tags: ionic4, seektotime

How can i track till where the user have watched the video in order to resume the video from that position when the user returns?
Like youtube, 
it actually knows which video is played till where.

Have checked the AndroidExoPlayer but the only supported platform is Android.
I need in both Android and iOS.

link for AndroidExoPlayer in ionic 4 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-exoplayer/

To check Instance members for AndroidExoPlayer 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/android-exoplayer/

Have even checked the plugin Media in ionic 4 but it is only for audio 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media

Comment: Just voting as negative won't help. If you would have let me know what i could do for reformatting my question with your negative vote would have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Videogular](https://videogular.github.io/videogular2/) might be a good option.
Here a couple of tips:

**vgUpdateTime($currentTime, $duration):** Called when progress time has been updated. Returns the current time and the total duration.
**seekTime(value, byPercent):** Seeks to a specified time position. Param value must be an integer representing the target position in seconds or a percentage. By default seekTime seeks by seconds, if you want to seek by percentage just pass byPercent to true.

Comment: I tried doing with videogular but while building the apk it shows following errors.


`ERROR in ./node_modules/videogular2/buffering.ts
ERROR in ./node_modules/videogular2/controls.ts
ERROR in ./node_modules/videogular2/core.ts
ERROR in ./node_modules/videogular2/overlay-play.ts
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library.`


While installing it through npm, these files are missing but on github repo, these files exists.
i tried doing it with taking a git clone too but same error persists.

Comment: Did you try including "node_modules/videogular2" in your tsconfig ? that might be a version issue. If it doesn't help, try using a previous version.

Comment: Apology for the late response.
And appreciate your quick response.

I tried doing it but the actual issue still persists.
there are few folders and files missing in the videogular2 directory.

How can i get those files and folders?

Comment: i downgraded the videogular2 to version 6.1.1 and the missing files and folders exists now.
Thank you so much!

Comment: SeekTime is working for .mp4 files but not for hls files.
The hls video is playing but the seektime function is not working.

I tried with these links and many more but couldn't find a solution.

[streaming/vg-hls](https://github.com/videogular/videogular2/tree/master/docs/modules/streaming/vg-hls)

[videogular2 issues](https://github.com/videogular/videogular2/issues/714)

Could you please help me out with that?